# Is <random> fully supported in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, random

I have this sample code and it throws an error:

```
std::random_device rd;     // only used once to initialise engine
std::mt19937 rng(rd);      // random-number engine used
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(0, 7); // guaranteed unbiased

int random_integer = uni(rng);
```

The error is:

> Error 1   error C2039: 'generate' : is not a member of
>   'std::random_device'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\random    1618    1   Life

Can somone explain me please, why is this happening? It seems to be an error in the header file and not in my code.

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

std::mt19937 has two constructors, one taking a single 32-bit unsigned value as parameter (default value 5489u), the other taking a seed-sequence (a template type) as a parameter. The latter is required to have a method called generate.
As a random_device does not have such a method, your code is not valid.
What you probably wanted to do is

```
std::mt19937 rng(rd());
```

That is extracting a value from the device and use that as a parameter.